# Spring Cloud Config Security with Git

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have to remove password and username from `application.yml` in config server to increase security and eventhough I have used SSH and I cant connect the rest of microservices with SSH.

Please check the `application.yml`

```
server:
  port: 8888
spring:
  application:
    name: configserver
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: true
      server:
        encrypt.enabled: false
        git:
          uri: {URI}
          clone-on-start: true
          searchPaths: 
          #ignoreLocalSshSettings: true
          skip-ssl-validation: true
          hostKey: GitLab
          hostKeyAlgorithm: ssh-rsa
          private-key: |
                        -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
                        -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: What's your basic goal?..Do you want encrypt password,then do that stuff in your code not in properties file

Comment: yes correct, I dont want in properties to have the username and password but somewhere else and somhow with ssh is not working

Comment: Can you show the log and dependency tree? ...seems to be some dependency issue

Comment: when i use ssh and i use: clone-on-start=true i get an error, otherwhise no

Comment: I hope you added **spring.cloud.config.server.git.cloneOnStart=true** in application.properties file or your yml file

Comment: i did, and when i add that, i get an error

Comment: Can you show the error log

Comment: Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: